# Block diagonal matrix from columns

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Suppose I have an `m x n` matrix A .
Is there a way to create `B`, a `(n x m) x n` matrix whose "diagonal" is formed by `A`'s columns ?

Example:

```
A = [1 2;
     3 4]  

B = [1 0;
     3 0;
     0 2;
     0 4]
```

Comment: Your example does not match, you end up with 2m x n

Comment: You're right! Fixed it! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way:

1. Convert `A` to a [cell array](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) of its columns, using [`mat2cell`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html);
2. From that cell array generate a [comma-separated list](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html), and use it as an input to [`blkdiag`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/blkdiag.html).

Code:

```
A = [1 2; 3 4];                                   %// example data
C = mat2cell(A, size(A,1), ones(1,size(A,2)));    %// step 1
B = blkdiag(C{:});                                %// step 2
```

This produces

```
B =
     1     0
     3     0
     0     2
     0     4
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short script to accomplish this. It works for any dimensions of A.

```
A=[1 2; 3 4];
[R C] = size(A);

for i=1:C
    B( 1+R*(i-1) : R*i , i ) = A(:,i);
end
```